# How to get Query String Value in Powerapps forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, power-automate

I need to get the query string values from the URL in powerapps.

i.e I have an SP list with Customized powerapps forms, if i pass the value in the URL like "http://TestSite.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/Lists/TestList/NewForm.aspx?CompanyName=Microsoft
&CompanyID=1".

I should able to get that CompanyName value and CompanyID value in powerapps forms. I tried Param(CompanyName) method but didn't get the value from query string.

Is there any solution to get the parameter value from query string in Powerapps.

Thanks in Advance!.

Comment: Just to double check have you tried using Param("CompanyName") with quotes? - Comment by [Nathan B](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/92658/Nathan-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Param** function does not work for SharePoint custom forms since it does not function as a canvas app. You will have to browse to the list form using the URL `"web.powerapps.com"` in order to get the query string.

I am not seeing other options to get the query string parameters if we stick in the customized form. Consider building a canvas app in PowerApps instead.

See a Power Apps Ideas post here (also has workarounds discussed): [SharePoint Custom Form - "Param" does not work.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/SharePoint-Custom-Form-quot-Param-quot-does-not-work/idi-p/126162)

Another article on this feature for your reference:
[Passing a Param object to a SharePoint PowerApp list form and why it doesn’t work.](http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2019/03/passing-a-param-object-to-a-sharepoint-powerapp-list-form-why-it-doesnt-work/)