# Sharepoint List default values from GET input

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

Is there a way in SharePoint to use arguments passed to the URL via GET requests as default arguments to a New Item on a List?

I have a list designed to track information about internal metrics. Each metric has a MetricID and will likely have multiple entries on the list. I can link members of my team to the New Item page for this list. However, I would like to be able to pass the MetricID to the New Item form without the team member having to enter it (as this can lead to human error).

I had the idea of using the a GET request, so the URL linked to would be something akin to:

https://*{CompanyName}*.sharepoint.com/sites/*{TeamName}*/Lists/MetricTracker/NewForm.aspx?**MetricID=AAA001**

As I will be sending the links to team members, I believe a GET request attached to the end of the URL would be the simplest way to implement this. However, I'm not completely tied to this strategy and so if I can create a *dynamic* default value, that would be great!

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you using classic experience or modern experience? Are you trying to populate MetricID field value from value given in URL query string parameter?

Comment: When I look for the Sharepoint Version, it just says 'SharePoint in Microsoft 365', but I believe this is the modern experience. Yes, I am trying to populate the field value from a URL parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to populate field values based on URL query string parameters using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

You have to customize the list form using Power apps. In Power apps, you can read query string parameters from URL using **Param()** function.

You have to store this query string parameter value in one variable in **OnStart** property/event of **App** object.

Then you can use this variable populate the MetricID field. You have to set the **Default** property of control based on this value.

You can follow this step by step article for more information: [Passing parameters to your Power Apps SharePoint form](https://www.about365.nl/2020/08/06/passing-parameters-to-your-power-apps-sharepoint-form/)

**Documentation**:

1. [Param function in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-param)

---

**Note**: The **Param** function does not work for SharePoint custom forms directly from SharePoint list since it does not function as a canvas app. So, you will have to browse to the list form using the URL `"web.powerapps.com"` in order to get the query string.

**Similar threads**:

1. [How to get Query String Value in Powerapps forms](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/285823/how-to-get-query-string-value-in-powerapps-forms).
2. [Passing a Param object to a SharePoint Power Apps list form and why it doesn’t work](http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2019/03/passing-a-param-object-to-a-sharepoint-powerapp-list-form-why-it-doesnt-work/)

---

You can vote on this idea to support using Param() function directly from SharePoint list: 
[SharePoint Custom Form - "Param" does not work](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/SharePoint-Custom-Form-quot-Param-quot-does-not-work/idi-p/126162)